# working graph in GraphEdit doesn't work in my app

Tags: c#, directshow, directshow.net

I have a composite-to-USB Video Capture Source and I want to render & save video. I created the graph using GraphEdit. I can see live video and save MPEG video successfully. But when I want to create exact graph in my code, I get "There is no common media type between these pins" error. Do you have any idea why?

Thanks

[image: The marked pin connection causes the error]

Comment: When it comes to "... between these pins", what are **these** exactly?

Comment: Video Capture Source to SampleGrabber. Actually I wrote on image desciption but it's not visible!

Comment: How exactly did you add video source filter to your graph? One good way is to enumerate video capture sources category and use moniker from that enumeration. One bad way (often causing problems like this) is just creating by CLSID.

Comment: You cannot connect SG input when media type is not compatible with SG. Typical reasons are: incorrectly set SG, video source exposing VIH2-formatted media type. There is n ocertainnty from Q description what is it in your case.

Comment: @RomanR. You are right. There was a problem with format compability. Well, I should convert YUY2 to RGB24 to connect SampleGrabber, because SampleGrabber works in RGB24. Do you have any idea how?

Comment: This is a conversion normally added automatically. SG does not have to do RGB24 - this is the way you set it up. Post some code to see what you are doing.